# how to do clustering based on distance when i already have the cluster head?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, distance

i am working on clustering in matlab. i already have a few cluster heads with points (10,15), (20,15),(18,27). around my cluster head,there are random points surrounding it. for example, the random points are (2,11), (6,16), (14,17), (22,25) and (17,12). i need to calculate the distance between my cluster heads and the random points and based on the minimum distance obtained when i calculate the distance, for example (2,11) is the nearest to (10,15), then i will cluster them together. may i know how should i do that in matlab? any idea on where should i start?

Answer (score 0):

This is really not an answer, but a comment.
To do it without knowing the cluster head
(1): calculate the pairwise-distance with seqpdist function.
(2): use the seqneighjoin function to get the phylogenetic tree.
(3): use cluster function to get the cluster. 
For your question, I guess you can write your own function instead of using the built-in matlab function.

Comment: how to write my own function?